# The merging lemma for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

(Merging lemma - Maybe it's not called like this in English, but it's how we call it at our university)

We'll say that than a family of sequences $(b_{1n}), (b_{2n}), ..., (b_{kn})$ spans the sequences $(a_n)$ if $\forall n: a_n = b_{rs}$ for exactly one pair $(r,s)$.

There's a well known theorem about sequences:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and $(b_1n), (b_2n), ..., (b_kn)$ span $(a_n)$. Then if all $(b_in)$ converge to $g$, then $a_n$ converges to $g$.

I thought about an analogical proposition for series

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and let $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ span $(a_n)$. If $\sum\alpha_n, \sum \beta_n$ are unconditionally convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is unconditionally convergent and $\sum a_n = \sum \alpha_n + \sum \beta_n$.

If we showed that $\sum a_n$ is unconditionally convergent, then $\sum a_n = \sum \alpha_n + \sum \beta_n$ would be trivial. But is  $\sum a_n$ is unconditionally convergent?

Comment: I don't see how this proposition could be true.  By your definition, $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ span $(a_n)$ if $\alpha_n = (a_n)$ (for example), so the proposition would fail in this case (if $ \beta_n$ doesn't sum to zero) .  Am I missing something?

Comment: Right, made the assumptions stricter